# Print a string with fprintf

Tags: c++, stl, stdio

I am having an issue with printing a string which im using for debug purposes.

I create the string like so:

```
//checker is int 
std::stringstream buttonx; 
buttonx << "Button" << checker << "_x";
```

Now i try to print it to my `error.txt` file

---

```
FILE * p;
p = fopen ("error.txt","w");
fprintf(p, "%s" , buttonx.str());
fclose(p);
```

The output is:

`,æ0`

Its different every time. I'm not sure whats going on was hopeing some could explain the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fopen` is plain C and cannot handle std::string. You need to input a `char*`, which you can access by calling `.c_str()` on the string, like this:

```
fprintf(p, "%s", buttonx.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Or, use a `std::ofstream` as the C++ gods intended.

Comment: How would std::ofstream syntax look ?

Comment: @Dave: `std::ofstream f("error.txt"); f << buttonx.str();`.  Or, if you're not writing anything else to the file, even `std::ofstream("error.txt") << buttonx.str();` might work.

Answer (score 0):

the function fprintf wants a null terminated string (a C string); you need the c_str() instead of yours:

```
 buttonx.c_str()
```